# Need to run complete test suite in Junit/TestNG from web page kind of tool

Tags: java, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver, web-testing

I have few test cases written in testNG and Junit using selenium for testing a webpage. But for executing them i need to go to command line or run them using eclipse each time i want to run. I want a centralised web page from where i can select what test i want to run and just click on some button to say run. And can see the output results on the same page. How could i achieve that?

Thanks-
Girish.

Comment: Have you tried using Jenkins/Hudson? You can always start those test using a technology like Maven or Ant.

Answer (score 0):

We use Jenkins in our project to do this kind of simplification when we want our business users to trigger tests. However, it may initially take some setup for each set of tests you want to run.